# Clay in well water

Tags: plumbing

Can an ultrafiltration unit really clean the oily colloidal clay out of our well water so it stops mucking up our pressure tank, GAC, and the resin in our softener? We want to know before we shell out $$$.

Comment: Ultrafiltration is a slippery word -- what is the exact filter specification in microns?

Answer (score 1):

Ultrafiltration is a buzz word, likely borrowed from large plants.  However, a 1 micron filter will remove clay particles.

I have a 3 stage filter followed  by UV light sterilization.  We collect rain water for drinking, which comes off asphalt roof, which is basically stones embedded in tar.  I use 1 micron, 5/10 micron and GAC cartridges.  It removes all the oil from this and the clay particles that get into the gutter.

The cartridges I use are  gradient density ones.  Which is the sort of mechanism and pressure, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafiltration), that ultrafiltration plants use.

[image]